# Should front marketing pages use a separate platform?

Tags: seo, cms, django

We have a Django website with a lot of backend code for the main functionality after a user logs in. But now we are trying to develop the first landing pages, improve the SEO, add FAQ pages etc. Really there is no programming needed here, just a CMS functionality.

There are CMS modules for Django, but since the team members who will work on this content are different from the main programming team, it seems to me there might be value in using a different platform for these front 'marketing' pages.

I've noticed such dynamic with some websites, like my bank's website seems to run the intro pages on a different server which can't tell if I am logged in to the banking website or not.

Any thoughts? Anyone have experience with this kind of scenario? Is it a good practice to use two platforms (kind of micro-services approach), or should I install a CMS module for our django website and keep it all in one monolithic code-base?